# How can I edit the location of the workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, workspace

Due to me being a novice before, I didn't understand what a workspace was. I thought there would be one workspace for each project. I placed my workspace in the folder of the project I was working on. Is there any way I can change the file location of my workspace, so that I don't have it in the folder of the first project, and instead someplace nicer, like the root folder of my programming folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move a workspace, you simply move its folder.

However, it seems you have projects in the workspace that are not in the workspace's folder.  In this case, you could move the projects as needed to create the desired folder hierarchy then move the workspace to the desired location. To move a project, select it the project and use the Refactor | Move menu command.

Another option would be to delete the workspace (by deleting it's hidden .metadata subfolder) and creating a new one. You'd loose all your workspace settings, though.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option under the File option in the menu to change the workspace.

File > Switch Workspace

[image]

Comment: But that seems to make a new workspace, which has different settings and whatnot. Is there a way to keep the same workspace for all my files?

Comment: try copying the .settings directory in your current workspace to the new workspace and then switching workspaces.  Make SURE you copy.